# How to increase the conversion for the reaction between 2-acetylpyridine and diamine?

Tags: organic-chemistry, reactivity

[image]

I tried refluxing in toluene using activated molecular sieves to absorb any water produced (didn't use Dean-Stark trap as it's a very small scale reaction).

This reaction isn't going by changing the time or temperature conditions. So, I added some (0.5 equivalent) triflic acid to increase the electrophilicity of the carbonyl. The reaction is proceeding but conversion isn't high. Is triflic acid a good choice for this reaction? Should I try using equivalent amount of triflic acid to increase the conversion?

Comment: Triflic acid is just going to protonate your diamine. Something like Ti(OiPr)4 might be a better option

Comment: https://doi.org/10.1016/j.poly.2008.04.028.
 This might be helpful. The starting material is slightly different (phenyl group instead of methyl) but I hope following similar procedure might help.

Comment: @SoumikDas I have read it already but as I said increasing temperature isn't working for me. here they have used reflux conditions only.

Comment: @SuchiGhosh This may be inappropriate to the question you asked. But I just wanted to know do you really need this particular reaction if it's not happening. Is there a possible way to bypass this step if you are doing a multi-step synthesis ? What might be occuring is that due to lot of methyl groups in the product, the conversion rate is not so high due to steric factors, so I was suggesting whether there can be any alternate way to reach the final goal.

Comment: Actually I do need to synthesize the imidazolidine ring where there is a methyl substitution at the imidazolidine-pyridine junction. The steric effect is  one of the reasons that this isn't going as expected. But in presence of acid it is converting to the desired product as the carbonyl will be more electrophilic. But I am not sure about the choice of acid.

Comment: @SuchiGhosh Hmmm... I see. May be you can try with glacial acetic acid if that works.

Comment: You haven't said how you are conducting the reaction. Try Dean-Stark trap and toluene solvent at reflux. No acid.

Comment: @user55119 tried refluxing in toluene using activated molecular sieves to absorb any water produced. Didn't use dean-stark as it's a very small scale reaction